# 2 threads working on 2 different object instances, but both instances state is changed when one thread change its own instance

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Very weird problem I'm working on:

I fill self.**movies** array this way:

```
    for movie_name in self.__movies_names__:
        movie = Movie(movie_name)
        self.__movies__.append(movie)
```

I create 2 threads this way: each MovieDetailsCollector has ITS OWN movie instance:

```
for movie in self.__movies__:
    print('starting movie "{0}"'.format(movie.name))
    mdc = MovieDetailsCollector(movie)
    threading.Thread(target=mdc.collectDetails).start()
```

Now, each thread runs this code:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    future_id_search = executor.submit(collector.collect_details_from_id_search)
    future_similar = executor.submit(collector.collect_similar)
```

The problem: When one thread executes 'collect_details_from_id_search', it changes the details of BOTH the instances, even the thread is not aware for the other instance (which is controlled by the other thread...).

for example, the 'movie' object holds a 'genres' member, which is a 'set' type.
the method 'collect...id_search' on thread-1 updates the 'movie' instance that the correlated 'collector' is holding, and also the other 'movie' instance!

I was looking for both 'movie' instances in each thread - and they are different! They have different memory location... and also the 'genres' field is located in a different address... but still one thread changes both of them.

I never encountered such thing.

Comment: If you want private members, use `__name`, not `__name__` as those are reserved. That said, provide a minimal example. Also make sure that different threads are actually possible, my guess is that the separate instances actually share some state, like class-statics or members initialized from identical objects.

Comment: thanks @UlrichEckhardt, I didn't declare my variables as instance-attributes, but as static. As I come from Java, I didn't notice, look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

As I come from Java, I thought that if I declare variables this way:

```
class Movie:
    name = ""
    genre = ""
```

Both name & genre are private. But I was wrong. Unlike Java, Python makes this variables class-variables (=static).

And when the 2 threads changed something, they changed it to the same static member, instead of different instances.

The correct way to declare instance-varialbes is:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie = ""
        self.genre = ""
```

Via the **init** method.